# How to avoid null NavigationController on a UIViewController after calling NavigationController.PopToViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm jumping back a few levels in the navigation stack using the NavigationController.PopToViewController(ancestor, true) method call.

This works great, except the new top view controller, the one to which I unwound, has a NagivationController set to null causing any new transitions to error out.

When I make the call to PopToViewController, the ancestor actually has a non-null NavigationController

Comment: Worth checking the array returned to see what controllers were popped. Any chance you could have pushed the same controller on more than once, resulting in it being disconnected on the pop?

Comment: Before calling PopToViewController the NagivationController's ViewControllers property has no VC's of duplicate types.  So nothing is on there twice.

Comment: I take it the controller being popped to is in the nav controllers list? Worth checking if it has a superview after the pop since if that is nil, that is probably why it cannot find its nav controller. If it has a superview look to see where it is in the hierarchy after the pop in case it has been moved somewhere.

Comment: Turns out... our navigation framework subclassed NavigationController and I needed to override PopToViewController to handle current view controller tracking for our framework.